# React - <BrowserRouter> doesn't render child div

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am implementing router in my react app but anything I place inside my `App.js` between `<BrowserRouter>` tags is not displayed.

**App.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

import Header from "./components/Header";
import UseToken from "./components/authentication/UseToken";

function App() {
  const { token, removeToken, setToken } = UseToken(); // setToken, token, removeToken

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Header token={removeToken} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Header.js**

```
function Header() {
  return <div>Hello world!!!</div>;
}

export default Header;
```

The above examples render a blank page at `localhost:3000`

I even tried modifying App.js to the following rudimentary code:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">Hello world...</div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And that didn't yield any results either.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update**
I'm looking into console and get the following error when including the BrowserRouter component:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Comment: I'm following this tutorial and they do not mention defining routes (cmd + f to "I told you that" to find the App.js browserrouter section). Is that code wrong?

https://dev.to/nagatodev/how-to-add-login-authentication-to-a-flask-and-react-application-23i7

Comment: `BrowserRouter` renders its children... I don't see any issue in your code shared. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue for us to inspect and debug live?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue on codesandbox so it seems that the problem isn't with the code per se. Please see my update with console error.

Comment: Any indication which hook call is invalid? Is there a code stacktrace of any kind? What version of `react-router-dom` are you using? Run `npm list react-router-dom` from your project's directory.

Comment: My understanding is that since my `App.js` consists only of the Hello World `<div>` then any hooks that may exist in other components would not be triggered this since nothing besides the `<div>` is being rendered. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You might just try killing and restarting any dev servers. Or uninstalling/reinstalling `react-router-dom` and restarting. The `DDRv6` higher-level routers use React hooks.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I have accidentaly installed `react-router-dom` in the parent folder of where all the other packages are installed. Removing the package and re-installing it in the correct location fixed this issue. Thanks and sorry again.

Comment: No worries... it happens. Voting to close as "unreproducible or caused by typo". Cheers and good luck.